# Upload de Arquivos em React Native

Tags: mobile, react, upload, react-native

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou iniciando na programação em react-native e estou com uma dúvida na utilização de forms para upload de arquivos.

É possível?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve passar o URL de algo como ImagePickerou CameraRoll(que deve ser semelhante a file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/shj15791-4v61-67g6-z1b6-v8451z956j5k.jpg) para, em formDataseguida, passá-lo junto com o pedido:

```js
const form = new FormData();

form.append('image', {
  uri: "file:///...",
  type: 'image/jpg',
  name: 'image.jpg',
});

fetch('https://example.com/api/upload', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: form
});
```